# Empty page instead of custom tomcat error page

Tags: tomcat, custom-error-pages

My setting: Apache 2.2 + Tomcat 6.0 @ Windows 2008 R2 64bit

- static webpages: /
- servlet: /foo
- tomcat and apache are connected by mod_jk
- 404.jsp is placed in tomcat\webapps\ROOT

**tomcat\conf\web.xml:**

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf:**

```
JkMount /foo/* worker1
JkMount /404.jsp worker1
```

When I open https://...../404.jsp my custom error page is displayed.
But when I open https://...../foo/nonexisting.html an empty page is displayed.

If I remove the `<error-page>...</error-page>` code from web.xml and open https://...../foo/nonexisting.html then tomcats own 404 is displayed.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see it, webapps' errors can't be handled with error pages placed in ROOT. I now put the 404.jsp in every webapp (/foo/404.jsp, /bar/404.jsp, ...) and now it works. I can safely delete the 404.jsp in ROOT, but if I delete the 404.jsp in /foo or /bar a blank page is served if a 404 occurres in either webapp. Either tomcat ignores the leading / in the "location" element or the content of this element is appended at the 'calling' webapp's path.

Answer (score 2):

The Jkmount should have the context as parameter, ex:

```
JkMount /mycontext/* worker1
```

then the pages are accessed this way:

```
https://mycontext/someservlet/
```

or

```
https://mycontext/foo/nonexisting.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: You need to be sure that the page you specify does not begin with a number (i.e.: 404.jsp). This because, according to Java Syntax, you cannot start a class name with a number.

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=492774

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: for 404.jsp a _404_jsp.java is generated which compiles to _404_jsp.class which is invoked without trouble, so this can't be the reason

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine when loading 404.jsp, and shows a blank page when tomcat actually tries to use the page to handle a 404 error, it could mean that there is an error in 404.jsp's source code that's only triggered by using the errorData object.

Check the logs. I was having a similar blank page problem and it turned out that I had an [incorrect taglib URL](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/12/according-to-tld-or-attribute.html).

**EDIT**

Also, JkMount should not be necessary since tomcat is already generating these 404s (i.e. they are not in Apache's purview).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, and it turns out the culprit was that I'd typed the name of the application context root into the error page location. That is,

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/MyApp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Whereas it should of course have been

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: as i answered myself some days ago: the location is appended to the webapps' path, so when a 404 occurs in the webapp with path /foo then /foo/{location} is served, so it seems one can't specify "global" error pages

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while running a static web project.I have done the following implementation, and it has worked for me.

Added the following lines in %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/web.xml

```
    <error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error_404.html</location>
    </error-page>
```

Answer (score -1):

Its shows exactly 404 page not found or else?
Because some other error codes also avail like 400,401,403,500.
Have a look at this link for this
http://docs.yahoo.com/docs/writeus/error.html

If you have any other add that error codes aslo in  web.xml file.
Hopes this helps.
Happy coding...

Comment: ? you must have misunderstood my problem